# Kernel dying while importing Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, anaconda

In anaconda3 after creating a new environment for tensorflow and installing tensorflow and keras. Whenever I import tensorflow, the kernel just dies.I tried importing numpy first and then tensorflow still no change.

I have dowloaded the latest version of tensorflow and anaconda (as of may 2020). Does anyone know what might cause this error?

Comment: did you try `conda update python` first? Just to make sure, you are not referring to `tensorFlow-gpu` right?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that one solution to this would be to downgrade the tensorFlow version and test to see if it works.